# Getting CSV headers without reading whole Stream

Tags: node.js, fs, node-csv-parse

I'm using the `csv-parser` node module to capture the headers of streaming csv files; there's a 'headers' event emitter I'm using that's built into the module.

I'm looping through an array of csv readstreams that I'm passing through my `getHeaders()` function. Right after I capture the headers of the streaming csv, I want to close that stream, then pass the next csv stream into the function so I can get those headers, then close the stream, and so on...

What is the best way to do this? I've tried a few different methods, including `.destroy()`, but I haven't found a solution that works. Maybe I am attempting to close the stream in the wrong spot? Here's what I have:

```
function getHeaders(dataStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dataStream
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('headers', (headers) => {
                let headerArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(headers);
                resolve(headerArray);                
                dataStream.destroy();
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
                reject(`err from readingFile ${err}`)
            })          
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about reading first 2 lines of stream and then piping array to csv as readable stream?

Try this:

```
const lineReader = require('readline');
const Stream = require('stream')

function getHeaders(dataStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let wantedLines = [];
       lineReader.createInterface({
         input: dataStream
       });
       lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
         if(wantedLines.length >= 2) {
           lineReader.close();
         }
       });
       lineReader.on('close', () => {
          let resolved = false;
          const readableStream = new Stream.Readable();
          readableStream
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('headers', (headers) => {
              if (!resolved) resolved = true;
              resolve(headers);
            })
            .on('error', reject);
            .on('close', () => {
              if (!resolved) resolve([]);
            });
          wantedLines.forEach(line => readableStream.push(line));
          readableStream.destroy();
       });
    });
}
```

Have not checked, comment if something wrong.